# How to export Azure Data Factory ARM template using Automation script to local drive?

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-powershell, azure-cli

I want to export the Azure Data Factory ARM template(from studio) to local drive using Automation script to push it to GitLab as ADF doesn't support native integration with GitLab.
How to export ADF ARM template through automation script (PowerShell, CLi, RestAPI etc.).
Please see attached ADF ARM template export page.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known limitation. You cannot programmatically export the ARM template.

> The export template feature doesn't support exporting Azure Data
> Factory resources. To learn about how you can export Data Factory
> resources, see [Copy or clone a data factory in Azure Data
> Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-clone-data-factory).

There are a number of similar requests shared [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/1219ec2d-6c26-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c#) [ADF shall be able to export ARM template by powershell](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/060ec746-6d26-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c) as Ideas and feedback, you can upvote or add one too for official MS response.

Comment: my pleasure.. 