# Do we have any way to export ADF Arm Template via Rest Api?

Tags: rest, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to export ADF Arm template via rest I didn't found any resources in official page as well, is there any way apart from exporting it manually ?

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately You cannot programmatically export the ARM template.
You have to manually export it.

[How to export Azure Data Factory ARM template using Automation script to local drive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71082193/how-to-export-azure-data-factory-arm-template-using-automation-script-to-local-d)